# ¿No se muestra mi checkbox en mi plantilla Metronic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy usando una plantilla Metronic y al crear el ***checkbox*** con ***input group*** no me aparece el checkbox pero si el input.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código

```html
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox">
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox">
          </span>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </form>
```

Comment: En tu ejemplo aparecen las casillas de verificación. A lo mejor hay algo más que no aparece en tu pregunta.

Comment: No se muestran los checkbox.

Comment: Claro que sí. Por favor haz click en los pequeños cuadraditos que aparecen al lado de los `<input type="text"`

Comment: Realmente no veo las casillas.